Solr backup not getting created for two collections out of three
I have Solr cloud version 9.5 with two nodes. I am trying to take Solr backup using the Solr backup API Bakup API - 'http://10.245.44.208:8982/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=274e126d-0ca2-4698-8e12-6d0ca27698be_backup&collection=274e126d-0ca2-4698-8e12-6d0ca27698be&location=file:///var/solr/data/pvcbackupstorage'
The API gives an error from which I can't understand much about where the problem is.
Api response -
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 500,
        "QTime": 15
    },
    "error": {
        "metadata": [
            "error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
            "root-error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
        ],
        "msg": "/var/solr/data/pvcbackupstorage/274e126d-0ca2-4698-8e12-6d0ca27698be_backup/274e126d-0ca2-4698-8e12-6d0ca27698be/zk_backup_0",
        "trace": "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: /var/solr/data/pvcbackupstorage/274e126d-0ca2-4698-8e12-6d0ca27698be_backup/274e126d-0ca2-4698-8e12-6d0ca27698be/zk_backup_0\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrResponse.getException(SolrResponse.java:56)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.api.CreateCollectionBackup.createCollectionBackup(CreateCollectionBackup.java:121)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.api.CreateCollectionBackup.invokeFromV1Params(CreateCollectionBackup.java:173)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.lambda$static$32(CollectionsHandler.java:1067)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.execute(CollectionsHandler.java:1264)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:319)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:297)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:226)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:932)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:880)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.dispatch(SolrDispatchFilter.java:262)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SolrDispatchFilter.java:219)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.traceHttpRequestExecution2(ServletUtils.java:249)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.rateLimitRequest(ServletUtils.java:215)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:213)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:210)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:598)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1580)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1553)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:228)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:301)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:822)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1598)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:287)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.run(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:199)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)\n",
        "code": 500
    }
}

What am I doing wrong and what is causing this issue?
I tried this for all the three collections I have in Solr, it is working for one but gives this error for other two.
